# Problem with relative path in Python

Tags: python, windows

I know this is a simple, beginner-ish Python question, but I'm having trouble opening a file using a relative path. This behavior seems odd to me (coming from a non-Python background):

```
import os, sys

titles_path = os.path.normpath("../downloads/movie_titles.txt")

print "Current working directory is {0}".format(os.getcwd())
print "Titles path is {0}, exists? {1}".format(movie_titles_path, os.path.exists(movie_titles_path))

titlesFile = open(movie_titles_path, 'r')
print titlesFile
```

This results in:

```
C:\Users\Matt\Downloads\blah>testscript.py

Current working directory is C:\Users\Matt\Downloads\blah
Titles path is ..\downloads\movie_titles.txt, exists? False

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Matt\Downloads\blah\testscript.py", line 27, in <module>
    titlesFile = open(titles_path, 'r')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '..\\downloads\\movie_titles.txt'
```

However, a dir command shows this file at the relative path exists:

```
C:\Users\Matt\Downloads\blah>dir /b ..\downloads\movie_titles.txt
movie_titles.txt
```

What's going on with how Python interprets relative paths on Windows? What is the correct way to open a file with a relative path?

**Also**, if I wrap my path in `os.path.abspath()`, then I get this output:

```
Current working directory is C:\Users\Matt\Downloads\blah
Titles path is C:\Users\Matt\Downloads\downloads\movie_titles.txt, exists? False
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Matt\Downloads\blah\testscript.py", line 27, in <module>
    titlesFile = open(titles_path, 'r')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Matt\\Downloads\\downloads\\movie_titles.txt'
```

In this case, seems like the `open()` command is automatically escaping the `\` characters.

**Embarrassing final update: Looks like I munged a character in the pathanme :) The correct way to do this on Windows seems to be to use `os.path.normpath()`, as I did originally.

Comment: The behavior of what? We need the output too.

Comment: I hit submit on accident too early, question is fixed now.

Answer (score 3):

`normpath` only returns a normalized version of that particular path. It does not actually do the work of *resolving* the path for you. You might want to do `os.path.abspath(yourpath)`.

Also, I'm assuming you're on IronPython. Otherwise, the standard way of expressing that string format would be:

```
"Current working directory is %s" % os.getcwd()
"Titles path is %s, exists? %s" % (movie_titles_path, os.path.exists(movie_titles_path))
```

(Sorry, this is only an answer to the halfway posted question. I'm puzzled about the full solution.)

Comment: Using the Python 2.6 Windows installer from python.org

Comment: I didn't know about the new string formatting in Py26 then. Good to learn :)